# Why does my code say that 'line' is not defined when I reference it outside of the for loop?

Tags: python

```py
def attack(n, file):
    global line
    j = randint(0, n-4)
    for i in range(0, j):
        line = file.readline()
    print(line[slice(0, len(line)-1)])
```

Why is `line` not defined in this statement?

```
print(line[slice(0, len(line)-1)])
```

Comment: Because `j` is zero in some cases (you're liable to get 0 as your random number), so `for i in range(0, j):` does nothing. You never enter the loop and so `line` never gets defined

Comment: why are you using `global` here? In any case, he for-loop body sometimes never executes, so `line` never gets assigned to (and there is no global `line` variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint

If you read the docs here, the values in `randint(...)` are inclusive. So, at some point, the value for `j` is equal to 0.

Since you are assigning a value to `line` inside the loop, and if the loop never executes, the variable `line` is never assigned a value.

You can either change the randint to:

```
randint(1, n-4) # assuming n > 4, otherwise you will get an error
```

Or assign a dummy value to `line` beforehand.

Comment: I did this and got this error: 
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (1,1, 0)